# bootcamp: automatic change of audio output device like in OSX ? (if headphones plugged in, mini toslink, ..)

Tags: bootcamp, windows, audio

I don't really know if it is like that for everyone or if there are some bootcamp driver issues on my machine, but:

Every time I plug in headphones, a mini-stereoplug or a optical mini-TosLink cable and want the sound to be played via the attached device, I have to open the output devices settings and choose the desired one and "set it to default". (windows 7 64bit, bootcamp w/ most recent drivers)
Is there some possibility to have an app do this automatically on (un-)plugging the cables or at least something that changes audio output device via a hotkey/combination?
Or should it change automatically out of the box and something is nessed up with my bootcamp drivers?

macbook pro 15", i7 late 2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Windows 7 does not automatically switch audio devices.  Nor do bootcamp drivers allow this to happen on Apple devices running Windows.

A quick search on the web brings up multiple articles about how to change the audio device more quickly (e.g., via a hokey, or small apps).  Here is one toolbar app found:

http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1656534

Comment: thanks, thought the usual windows tools wouldn't work for bootcamp driver stuff.

Comment: I beg to differ. For the past 3 years I've been running Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro and it has always switched audio device automatically when I have plugged in headphones. Although for some reason mines has stopped doing so and I am surprised at the number of people having this problem as it has always worked fine for me prior to this. I should also add that my problem is specific to flash player as it doesn't use the built-in speakers when there are no headphones plugged in but other applications work fine.

Answer (score 1):

1. Activate the **'Mute the rear output device when a front headphone
   plugged in'** under the advanced settings menu.
2. Click on the Folder Icon next to Analog.
3. Click on the **'Disable Front Panel Jack Detection'** button.

I've got both green connectors set to headphone.

It has always worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

you can easily set your headphone as default device. as soon you unplug headphone jack device switch to your speaker and when connect headphone it will switch back to it.